# is this valid CSS?

Tags: css

Im trying to create a class called "deadlink" which is for any link within the GP_Content DIV, would this be valid?

```
/* unvisited link */           
div.GP_content .deadlink a:link 
{
color:#666666;
border-bottom:1px dotted #000000;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want:

```
div.GP_content a.deadlink:link
{
    color: #666666;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you intended for your deadlink class to be on the link then you'd want your selector to be the following.

```
div.GP_content a.deadlink:link
```

Answer (score 0):

It is valid, but it works for links inside an element with the class `deadlink`, inside a `<div>` with the class `GP_content`.
May not be what you intend.

Answer (score 0):

```
div.GP_content .deadlink a:link { ... }
```

What you've written targets all links inside elements of class deadlink which are inside the div.  It sounds like what you want is actually to target links of class deadlink inside the div.  That would be like this:

```
div.GP_content a.deadlink:link { ... }
```

However, from your description, it sounds like you want to target all links within the div.  If it is all, rather than specific ones, just use this to target all links within the div:

```
div.GP_content a:link { ... }
```